# Improve "user was removed" display in achievements panel

Tags: feature-request, deleted-users

When I looked at my achievements and saw a -10 User was removed, I racked my brain trying to think of when I asked or answered a question with that title, and why it had so many downvotes.

When I clicked on the link, it took me to a page about my user, and I had a brief panic that it was my user that had been removed for some sort of ToC violation.

It would be much better if "User was removed" did not look the same as a question with that title would look, e.g. if it was in italic, in a different colour, or with a background colour or something.

Also, when I click the link in "User was removed", I should be taken to the help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed, rather than to my own user page, if it is not possible to usefully link to something specific about the user that has been removed, or to the answer that has changed rep.

Clarification edit: The main problem is that the notification looks identical to how a question with the title "User was removed" would look, but it's' a very different thing. See screenshot:

[image: User was removed notice]

Comment: Doesn't the link take you to [your rep overview](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3408/rjmunro?tab=reputation)?

Comment: The user was removed link *does* go to the help page mentioned?

Comment: @JonClements: The one in your rep overview does. The one in the notification may not? Not sure...

Comment: @Cerbrus It does go to the rep overview, but that is a page about me as a user, and I've just clicked "User was deleted" and been taken to a page about my user, therefore I think "I've been deleted, WTF is going on? Have I been hacked? Have I done something against TOS?" There's nothing clear on that page (for me at least) showing the loss of 10 rep for the deletion.

Comment: @rjmunro I think it takes you there so you can look at your rep history to find what's happened. If *your* account was deleted then you'd no longer have a login.

Comment: And if _your_ account was deleted, you'd have gotten a different message.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, but as I haven't experienced my account being "deleted" before, how am I supposed to know that?

Comment: To be blunt: common sense. If a site this large deletes your account, you can be sure you just get logged off  with a __very__ clear message why your account is deleted.

Comment: I agree with the others that the third person "user was removed" is pretty clearly referencing someone else and that should be obvious - although there might be no harm in making it clearer, á la "Removed vote from deleted user"

Comment: @Pekka웃 "Removed vote from deleted user" is an improvement, but IMHO it needs to not look the same as a question with that title would look, e.g. by putting it in italic, or on a different colour background or something.